# Error with Broadcast Receiver which should to work with 13 broadcasts

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

```
Error in mainTest(ru.myitschool.lab23.InstrumentedTestLab46):
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Throwable:      'an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without transformation to match: is "ACTION_ASSIST"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without transformation to match: is "ACTION_ASSIST"
     Got: view.getText() was "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" transformed text was "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"
View Details: MaterialTextView{id=2131231135, res-name=status_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2105, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED, inp...
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.ThrowableHandler.handle(ThrowableHandler.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:5)
    at ru.myitschool.lab23.DescriptionFailureHandler.handle(InstrumentedTestLab46.kt:244)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:5)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:12)
    at io.github.kakaocup.kakao.delegate.ViewInteractionDelegate.check(ViewInteractionDelegate.kt:26)
    at io.github.kakaocup.kakao.text.TextViewAssertions$DefaultImpls.hasText(TextViewAssertions.kt:53)
    at io.github.kakaocup.kakao.text.KTextView.hasText(KTextView.kt:18)
    at ru.myitschool.lab23.InstrumentedTestLab46$mainTestCheckStep$1.invoke(InstrumentedTestLab46.kt:150)
    at ru.myitschool.lab23.InstrumentedTestLab46$mainTestCheckStep$1.invoke(InstrumentedTestLab46.kt:138)
    at io.github.kakaocup.kakao.screen.Screen.invoke(Screen.kt:119)
    at ru.myitschool.lab23.InstrumentedTestLab46.mainTestCheckStep(InstrumentedTestLab46.kt:138)
    at ru.myitschool.lab23.InstrumentedTestLab46.mainTest(InstrumentedTestLab46.kt:128)
    ... 8 trimmed
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable:      'an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without transformation to match: is "ACTION_ASSIST"' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without transformation to match: is "ACTION_ASSIST"
     Got: view.getText() was "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" transformed text was "android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"
View Details: MaterialTextView{id=2131231135, res-name=status_text, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=2105, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@YYYYYY, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED, inp...
    at ru.myitschool.lab23.DescriptionFailureHandler.handle(InstrumentedTestLab46.kt:234)
    ... 19 more
```

MainActivity:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView statusText;
    BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        statusText = findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        myBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver makeBroadcastReceiver() {

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_APPLICATION_RESTRICTIONS_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_APPLICATION_LOCALE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_ASSIST);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);

        this.registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, filter);

        return myBroadcastReceiver;
    }

    private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public MyBroadcastReceiver() {
        }

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            statusText.setText(intent.getAction());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

I had a task to create a Broadcast Receiver that could receive 13 different broadcasts and output their value to `statusText`, that is, if we have `ACTION_TIME_TICK` broadcast, then the text ACTION_TIME_TICK should be set in `statusText`. Method `makeBroadcastReceiver()` which return Broadcast Receiver is required by the task.
In our training, most of the information has to be searched for myself, so I even had to work on it for several days, looking for information on how to do it, this is my first time working with Broadcast Receiver.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a bad UI test — you should not register receiver in system, or register it with a flag `Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED`:

```kotlin
this.registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);

// or ContextCompat version (preferred)
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(this, myBroadcastReceiver, filter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
```

UI test for this task creates `BroadcastReceiver` from your's `MainActivity. makeBroadcastReceiver` method, then checks it against list of `Intent.ACTION_*` described in task. Btw, check carefully all action's names — some of them presented differently from corresponding constant name